# How to fix: Materialize navbar dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, materialize

I am working with Laravel 6 and using Materialize CSS along with jQuery.
One of the navbar-dropdowns I made (shown in code) is giving me the following error (shown in picture)

I have tried by getting the class name as well as id name in jQuery, but neither one works at all.`

## Navbar dropdown:

```
<a class="dropdown-trigger"
id="dropdown-init"
data-target="dropdown"
href="{{ route('login') }}"> {{ __('Login') }} </a>
```

## Dropdown content:

```
<ul class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown">
  <li>
    <form action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
        <button class="btn green darken-4 white-text" type="submit">
          {{ __('Logout') }}
        </button>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## jQuery initializer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
});
```

## Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Looking in to the Materialize docs, the errors that youre having is because you changed materialize id's and classes. You can't changed them because there variables for there specific function.

Replacing them is obvious that it will throw an error because you replaced it with your angular code. I recommend you playing on which functions you can take and test it evreytime, when it breaks you will know that code you took is indispensable.

Good luck!